# set axis limits when using groupby

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with groups of data that need to be plotted.  They are a sequence of topographic profiles where the data for the first one has the value of 1 in the LINE_ID field, and so on.    I successfully created the plots using a stackoverflow answer by KAt from Jul 15, 2022.

Here is the code from the original answer, modified for my purpose:

```py
groupby = stackprofile.groupby('LINE_ID')    
lines = list(stackprofile['LINE_ID'].unique())

for i in lines:   
    line1 = groupby.get_group(i)
    x = line1['FIRST_DIST']
    y = line1['FIRST_Z']
    #ymin = line1['FIRST_Z'].min
    plt.figure(figsize=(18,14))
    plt.scatter(x, y, c = "blue", s= 40)
    #plt.ylim(ymin,(ymin+2))
    plt.xlabel('FIRST_Z')
    plt.ylabel(i)
```

This makes the graphs that I want, with separate graphs based upon the value in the field LINE_ID.  But, I want the y axis for each graph to be scaled from the minimum value in that group (defined by value in LINE-ID field) to a maximum of the minimum value plus an arbitrary value (2 in this example).  I attempted this in the lines of code that are commented out.

I get this error if I run the above code with all lines active:

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'method'.

I need help in controlling the y axis.  For each graph, the y-axis minimum value needs to be the minumum value for that group of data and the y-axis maximum value needs to be determined based upon the minimum value.

Comment: You want `line1['FIRST_Z'].min()`.  Without the parenthesis, the result is a function ("a method"), with the parenthesis the result is the function applied to the given data.

Comment: That works.  Thanks.